# Iterate over class method using other class method in same Python class

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone give me an explanation with intuition as to why I can loop over this one class method using my other class method according to example below? I have another code built in the same way for a bigger task following exactly this logic.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['a', 'a', 'b','b','b','c','c']
                  ,'col2' : [1, np.nan, 2,2,np.nan,2,2]
                   ,'col3' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                  })

class test(object):


def __init__(self):
    print ("Started an instance of a class")
    
def add(self, df):
    self.df = df
    self.df['col4'] = self.df['col2'] + self.df['col3']
    
    return self.df['col4']
        
def subset(self, df, str_disc_grp):
    self.df = df
    self.str_disc_grp = str_disc_grp
    
    list_disc_grp = self.df[self.str_disc_grp].drop_duplicates()
    for disc_lvl in list_disc_grp:
        print ("Iteration is for level: {}".format(disc_lvl))
        df_sub = self.df[self.df[self.str_disc_grp] == disc_lvl]
        df_temp = self.add(df_sub)
        display(df_temp)

        # do other stuff....

class_test = test()

# Dosent work
class_test.subset(df, str_disc_grp='col1')
```

Result is below for calling class method with for-loop, it doesn't seem to capture the other levels of 'col1':

```
Iteration is for level: a
0    2.0
1    NaN
Name: col4, dtype: float64
Iteration is for level: b
Series([], Name: col4, dtype: float64)
Iteration is for level: c
Series([], Name: col4, dtype: float64)
```

Doing something along the lines of below works, of course, without problems:

```
# Does work
list_disc_lvl = df['col1'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
for subset_lvl in list_disc_lvl:
    bool_temp = (df['col1'] == subset_lvl)
    df_sub = df[bool_temp]

    display(df_sub)

    # do other stuff
```

Result for sub-selection summary given normal for-loop below:

```
0    2.0
1    NaN
Name: col4, dtype: float64
2    5.0
3    6.0
4    NaN
Name: col4, dtype: float64
5    8.0
6    9.0
Name: col4, dtype: float64
```

Thanks in advance!
/swepab